# Android ListView notifyDataSetChanged() from Service

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a background service which receive messages from a server and with those message it updates inner properties of objects which are shown in a ListView.

I always uses the runOnUiThread method to run the listArrayAdapter.notifyOnDataSetChanged() command.

From some reason sometimes the ListView is refreshed and it does show me the property update and sometimes it doesn't..

For testing i've added a "refresh" Button to my ListView and when it pressed the listArrayAdapter.notifyOnDataSetChanged() is executed.

Every click on the button the view is refreshed perfectly..

I can't really understand why when trying to refresh from the service it doesn't always work but i think i maybe not always runs on the UIThread...

I'm really hopeless and will glad to get help..

**My Code**

**ServerConnectionManager.java** - extends Service

```
//example of a command executed when a specific message received from the server:
//app is the Application variable
    public void unFriend(int userId)
    {
        serverResponseManager.onUnFriend(app.getApplicationFriend(userId),false);
    }
```

**ServerResponseManager.java** - a class that handle all application responses to server messages:

```
    public void onUnFriend(FacebookUser facebookUser, boolean isYouRemovedClient) {                 

         //this is the property which will effect the ListView view when calling the  
         //arrayListAdataper.notifyOnDataSetChanged();
        facebookUser.setApplicationFriend(false);        
        app.getApplicationFriends().remove(facebookUser);
        app.getDatabaseManager().deleteApplicationFriend(facebookUser.getId());         

         //if the application is currently running in the UI (not on the background) it will run a method inside the BaseActivity
        if (app.isApplicationInForeground())
        {           
            app.getCurrentActivity().onUnFriend(facebookUser);
            if (isYouRemovedClient)
                app.showToast(facebookUser.getName() + " has removed from your friends", true);
            else
                app.showToast(facebookUser.getName() + " has removed you from friends", true);
        }
    }
```

**BaseActivity.java** - an Activity which set all default configuration for all Activities which extends it

```
//in this exemple the BaseActivity method does nothing but the ListViewActivity.java method override it
public void onUnFriend(FacebookUser facebookUser)
{                   

}
```

**ListViewActivity.java** - extends BaseActivity and have a ListView in it which should reflect the change in the FacebookUser object property which being made in public void onUnFriend(FacebookUser facebookUser, boolean isYouRemovedClient) in ServerResponseManager.

```
@Override
public void onUnFriend(FacebookUser facebookUser)
{       
    updateView();
}

private void updateView()
{
    runOnUiThread(updateViewRunnable());
}

private Runnable updateViewRunnable()
{
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {             
            listArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    return run;
}
```

Comment: Using `runOnUiThread` most certainly will make the passed `Runnable` run on the UI thread. It would be a good idea if you post some code, because it might be some kind of concurrency issue you're having.

Comment: you're more then right... i've added some code examples

Comment: I think you should add Log before listArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); so that you can know whether the notifyDataSetChange execute or not, and when it executes. This will help you find the question much quickly.

Comment: I'm guessing that your `updateView()` method is not always being called when you think it should be. Have you added some logging to check that? Also, how are the methods `isApplicationInForeground()` and `getCurrentActivity()` implemented? It is possible, that by using a Service instead of a Thread the behaviour of these methods has changed.

Comment: If you just want a resolution and necessary a fix for your problem, I would advice you to register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will receive updates (you service should broadcast instead of notifying ListView)

Answer (score 9):

Don't mix business logic. It looks so complicated that is hard to read.

1. In your service, broadcast an intent with information about update.
2. In `Activity` where `ListView` is, create and register `BroadcastReceiver` with `IntentFilter` for your update events.
3. In `onReceive` method of your `BroadcastReceiver` handle update events, for example update list.

Comment: This also works well with `LocalBroadcastManager`, available in the Android Support package, for keeping your "broadcasts" solely within your app. Or, try Otto: http://square.github.com/otto/

Comment: Yes, good point. BTW @CommonsWare thanks for the photo on droidconUK ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Cursor in your ListView to display your Data.
The Service writes/updates the Data in your ContentProvider. At the End of your Database Transaction you simple use:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(PROVIDER_URI,null);
```

and your ListView gets updated automaticly.

Comment: So basicly you need some ContentProvider, which is some kind of more work than a BroadcastReceiver solution. Override for example the #insert Method of your Content Provider and do your Inserts. Very important is that your Cursor and Content Provider Point to the __same__ URI as this make the update from within a ContentProvider so easy.

Answer (score 1):

A Service should usually independent from UI concerns. A great way to decouple services and UI related stuff is the event bus pattern. For Android, check out https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus.

In the ServerConnectionManager, you could post an event:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new UnfriendEvent(userId));
```

Now register your activity to the event bus, and the event will be delivered to the activity by calling the onEvent method:

```
public void onEventMainThread(UnfriendEvent event) {...}
```

Like this, you decouple your components leading to a neat and clean software design, which is very flexible to changes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use

notifyDataSetChanged on onDestroy of service.

the list view will get refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial for proper architecture of your code

[developing an app with a background service](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/)

It shows how to receive notifications from the service and update the UI.

runOnUiThread is mostly used before AsyncTask calls are made. I think you should use a handler instead (it updates the UI and allows the thread to run). Try using the handler and see what happens