# update listview in my activity from service android

Tags: android, android-service-binding

I having 2 classes ,

1.Activity class

2.Service class

I need to update my list view in my activity,when service got any updates.
Actually i trying like an chat application , My services always checking my db and if it got any new string , i need to update in my activity without rebuild the again only i need to refresh the list view. i found it will be  manipulated using iBinder , But i don't how to use it. Can any one suggest me with some examples of code .

[referred pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145109/android-listview-notifydatasetchanged-from-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a Bound Service. I did the something similar in my application. Where upon clicking refresh, I invoke a service which gets data in background and updates the UI.

Check out my service here:
https://github.com/madhur/GAnalytics/blob/develop/src/in/co/madhur/ganalyticsdashclock/AnalyticsDataService.java

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(AnalyticsAccountResult result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    App.getEventBus().post(result);
}
```

Activity:
https://github.com/madhur/GAnalytics/blob/develop/src/in/co/madhur/ganalyticsdashclock/MainActivity.java

```
@Subscribe
public void UpdateUI(AnalyticsAccountResult result) {
    ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbHeaderProgress);
    LinearLayout spinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.spinnerslayout);
    TextView statusMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusMessage);

    switch (result.getStatus()) {
        case STARTING:
        statusMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;

        case FAILURE:
        statusMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        statusMessage.setText(result.getErrorMessage());
        break;

        case SUCCESS:
        statusMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (result.getItems() != null)
        {
            this.acProfiles = result.getItems();
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(acProfiles, this);
            listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            UpdateSelectionPreferences();
            if (result.isPersist() && acProfiles.size() > 0)
            {
                if (App.LOCAL_LOGV)
                Log.v(App.TAG, "saving configdata");        
                try
                {
                    appPreferences.saveConfigData(acProfiles, credential.getSelectedAccountName());
                }
                catch (JsonProcessingException e)
                {
                    Log.e(App.TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

It would also helpful to use Otto library:
http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you have the activity class named MainActivity where you initialized your ListView with the adapter named listviewAdapter. Put this code inside MainActivity:

```
  public static Handler UIHandler;

    static {
        UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    public static void runOnUI(Runnable runnable) {
        UIHandler.post(runnable); 
    }
```

When you made changes to your listview data inside your service class,  write this code to apply new data to the ListView:

```
MainActivity.runOnUI(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            MainActivity.listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is nice, working for now, but am afraid for some thread related exceptions after :/

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I cannot provide any useful code examples, however I think what you may be looking for is a ListAdapter. A ListAdapter takes a listview and a dataset (in your case maybe an array of strings) and combines the 2. Whenever the dataset changes (in your case this would be when your service detects a new string and adds it to the array) you just call ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and the listview will be automatically updated with your new information.
Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html for more info on the specific ListAdapter you might use.

Comment: Thanx for your reply,..Actually you are right.But My question is how do i know that datasetchanged from my activity..How should i get intimated from my service.?

Comment: I have not had to do this personally so I cannot say for sure which method is the best, but I think a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) would work for you. It is an abstract class which can handle messages broadcast by a service. The service will use it's sendBroadcast() method when it finds a new string and your activity will be registered as a BroadcastReciever which will perform some action when a broadcast is received.