# Regularly update the ListView of a chatroom

Tags: android, web-services

I develop an Android app with a chat and I would like to contact every 10 seconds my API to retrieve new messages and to display them in the ListView of my Activity.

If I use a service to retrieve messages, I can't update the ListView because the service and the activity are not in the same context, so the service can't call a callback function.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: search for "**update activity from service**" a lot of options

Comment: Better go for service, of course you can update listview from service [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463538/update-listview-in-my-activity-from-service-android)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) or event bus like [otto](http://square.github.com/otto/)

For example with otto, In your activity

```
@Subscribe public void onGetMessage(GetMessageEvent event) {
    // Update your listview here
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}
```

In your service, after you get new message , post event to activity.

```
BusProvider.getInstance().post(new GetMessageEvent(messageObj));
```

Don't forget to create GetMessageEvent class,

```
public class GetMessageEvent {
    public Message message;

    public GetMessageEvent(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```